# Row Transposition Encryption/Decryption C++

Tags: c++, encryption, visual-c++

Okay i'm doing a encryption code for row transposition and so far everything is running smoothly except the fact that the code isn't reading the columns correctly. I don't know how to really explain it but its reading the first column correctly but for the rest it messes it up and reads it in the wrong order. My code is suppose to have it read the columns based users input.

I've tried modifying the parameters of how it is but still no luck so i'll give an example of what i'm doing :
plaintext : i am thick
key : 2 1 3

i know that its suppose to look like :

| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | A | M |
| T | H | I |
| C | K | X |

and when encrypted it suppose to show :
ahkitcmix

but my code is printing :
MIXAHKITC

so its going "321" and not doing it the order of "213" as intended from the matrix.

I included a little of my code but any help would do.

```
string encryptRowTransposition(const string& plaintext, const string& key) {
    string modifiedText = removeSpaces(plaintext);
    vector<int> transpositionMatrix = generateTranspositionMatrix(key);
    int numRows = transpositionMatrix.size();
    string paddedText = addPadding(modifiedText, numRows);
    int numCols = paddedText.length() / numRows;
    string ciphertext;

    // Create a matrix to store the plaintext
    vector<vector<char>> matrix(numRows, vector<char>(numCols));
    int index = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
        for (int row : transpositionMatrix) {
            matrix[row - 1][col] = paddedText[index++];
        }
    }

    // Read out the ciphertext column by column
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
            ciphertext += matrix[row][col];
        }
    }

    return ciphertext;
}
```

and here is the matrix function for those who just asked :

```
    vector<int> generateTranspositionMatrix(const string& key) {
    vector<int> transpositionMatrix;
    string numStr;
    for (char c : key) {
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            numStr += c;
        }
        else if (!numStr.empty()) {
            transpositionMatrix.push_back(stoi(numStr));
            numStr.clear();
        }
        }
    if (!numStr.empty()) {
        transpositionMatrix.push_back(stoi(numStr));
        }
     sort(transpositionMatrix.begin(), transpositionMatrix.end(), 
     greater<int>());
     return transpositionMatrix;
     }
```

Comment: We need the `generateTranspositionMatrix` method at the very least. One hint is to **always** use zero based indexing. If your key is not zero based then **first** convert it to zero based, and then continue. Crypto is full of modulo ops and one-based calculations generally don't work well for those, or for array access etc.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. See where the behavior differs from what you expect.

Comment: Beware that `++col` only executes after the first iteration, so it may not do what you expect (unless it is some IMHO misplaced trick to optimize the code).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I just went and updated the post with the required generatetranspositionmatrix for you to see

Comment: `numStr += c;` ? Are you sure `c` is a char, so you're reconstructing the key? Adding the column indicators together also doesn't seem what you want to do. I'd definitely test such functions separately before using them.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes well thats the function my group partner had used and they sent me this because they got stuck lol so yea... im looking at it now though to see if it is being properly used.

Comment: `generateTranspositionMatrix` cannot distinguish between `2 1 3` or `3 1 2` or in fact any other permutation, because it does a `sort` at the end. Whatever permutation you pass as a parameter, you will get the same result of `[3, 2, 1]`